# Проблема с передачей аргумента сторонней программе в Java code - обработка пробелов в строковом аргументе

Tags: java, windows, cmd

Есть консольная утилита ring, существующая в виде файла ring.cmd. На вход она принимает строку с параметрами, одним из параметров является путь к папке.

Пишу приложение-обертку над ring на Java (https://github.com/miller7777777/LicDataExtractor).

Столкнулся с проблемой:

Если путь не содержит пробелов, все работает штатно.

Если путь содержит пробелы, ring выкидывает ошибку, это ожидаемо. Для нормальной работы путь к папке надо заключить в кавычки.

Вот тут и начинается проблема: При передаче в ring закавыченной строки в java коде ring возвращает ошибку. При передаче в него этой же самой закавыченной строки в командной строке Windows все работает штатно.

Можно как-то решить эту проблему, или городить велосипед с созданием временной папки, путь к которой не содержит пробелов, копированию в нее файлов данных и работе затем с этой папкой? Хотелось бы избежать такого варианта.

Фрагмент кода:

```
public class Extractor {

    private String fullDirectoryName;
    private String pinCode = null;
    private String regNumber = null;
    private String result;
    private String licFileName;
    private List<String> regDataList = new ArrayList<String>();

.............................

private void getPinRegNumber(String fullDirectoryName, String licFileName) {
        try {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("ring.cmd license list --path ")
                    .append("\"")
                    .append(fullDirectoryName)
                    .append("\"");
//            String argument = "ring.cmd license list --path " + "\"" + fullDirectoryName + "\"";
            String argument = sb.toString();

            System.out.println("Argument = " + argument);
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(argument);

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream(), "windows-1251"));

            // read the output from the command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the getPinRegNumber command:\n");
            String s = null;
            if ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
                String pinReg[] = s.split("-");
                pinCode = pinReg[0];
                regNumber = pinReg[1];
            }

// read any errors from the attempted command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the getPinRegNumber command (if any):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            proc.waitFor();
            proc.destroy();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Для таких задач лучше использовать [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), а не `Runtime.exec()`.